# Why tmediaplayer.CurrentTime not working for Android?

Tags: firemonkey, android-music-player, audiotrack, trackbar, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to make control audio with tackBar
I use this code
When audio is playing, my code on timer is

```
If trackbar1.max<>mediaplayer1.duration then 
  trackbar1.max := mediaplayer1.duration;

If trackbar1.value<>mediaplayer1.currentTime then 
  trackbar1.value :=mediaplayer1.currentTime
```

This code works perfectly for windows, but on Android no (trackbar keep changing up down up down)

Comment: I start the timer only when mediaplayer Stat is playing, the same code when I run it on windows work fine, but on Android not working (current time not work well, same value (-)),

Comment: I use the same code before in rad studio 10.1 work perfectly in Android, but not work now in 10.3.2

Comment: I tested it before but didn't work, I will try it again when I back home, you're not boring me brother, you helping me and I'm so thankful for you 

Comment: Same problem brother, the problem on mediaplayer1.currentTime not working on rad studio 10.3.2 at Android platforms

Comment: I test on Android 9, I test with an other phone, the same thing, I make an other test, show mediaplayer1.duration on a label, values Sametimes negative examples : 1765890, 2855438, - 67865, 40989876.. Ets 2 values positive 1 value negative

Comment: I installed old version 10.2.3 I use the same code works perfectly 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's a bug ([RSP-19678](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19678)).
2. You may get fix from [this repository](http://git.kngstr.com/KngStr/delphi-fixes/src/7ee91c7c74594a38744594238ce11a51bddea79e/10.2.3/Fixes).

Comment: Please elaborate briefly the content to where the linke refers. It might expire in the future rendering your answer obsolete, flagged > removed as answer.